# Displaying *(star) superscript in R - expression( )

Tags: r, superscript

is there any way to display superscript of *(star), with the expression() function? I am trying to display this in a graph produced in ggplot2. I have tried

```
expression(a^{*})
```

but does not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
plot(rnorm(30), xlab = expression(paste("a"^"*")))
```

Comment: Or just `plot(rnorm(30), xlab = expression(a^"*"))` (no need for `paste()`)

Comment: For completeness' sake, use `expression(a["*"])` for subscript.  A bit counter-intuitive - LaTeX users would expect it to be `_`.