# Superscripted star in geom_label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a superscripted star in a `geom_label` from a data frame string, but can't find a solution.

A minimum working example would be

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1, l = "P^2")
# the real data.frame has more observations with other expressions as well

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, label = l)) + 
  geom_label(parse = T)
```

But instead of having P^2 I want to display P^*. However, neither `"P*"`, `"P^*"`, `latex2exp::TeX("P^\\star", output = "character")`, nor any additional `\`'s help me out in this case.

## Edit

If you are looking for using expressions (and a star) inside of a geom_label, text (annotate) or some other geometric that uses text from a data.frame (i.e., you assign the value within the `aes`-function), then this might help you.

If you want to use an expression (and a star) within an axis-label, title, or other text that is directly assigned outside of the `aes`-function (i.e., `labs(x = "my expresion here")`), then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826597/displaying-star-superscript-in-r-expression) will help you out!

Comment: While its a similar question, its not a duplicate (IMHO), as `expression(P^"*")` does not work within a data.frame.

Comment: better like this?

Comment: Excellent, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After having written the question, I finally found the answer to be simply `"P^'*'"`. But because I couldn't find the solution anywhere else, I wanted to leave the answer here.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1, l = "P^'*'")

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, label = l)) + 
  geom_label(parse = T)
```